# How to check in Python for each element of a list, whether it is contained in another list?

Tags: python, list, boolean-expression, comparison-operators

How does it work in Python to check for each element of a list (say `l1`), whether it is contained in another list (say `l2`).

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['b', 'c']
```

The desired output is `[False, True, True]`. So I really want a boolean vector of `len(l1)` and not some kind of intersection like `['b', 'c']` etc. My questions differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138015/checking-if-any-elements-in-one-list-are-in-another) in the sense that it is not sufficient for my problem to know whether there *any* element from the first list contained in the second, but *which* elements are, and which are not.

Comment: Related: [How to check if a value in one list is in another list with a one-liner for an if statement in Python if I'm not using sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45098771/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse the question behind your link, aims at finding *any* match, which is what I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[x in l2 for x in l1]
```

Explanation:

- I find it to be understood best, when starting with the `for x in l1` part: a temporary variable `x` is created and looped all elements in `l1` similar to a [for loop](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).
- for each of this `x` it is now checked, whether it is in `l2` (so the `in` in `x in l2` has a different meaning than the `in` in `x in l1`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy array`, and the function [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
import numpy

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['b', 'c']
results = numpy.in1d(l1, l2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are two lists, `l1` and `l2`, and we have to check if each element of `l1` is present in `l2`, it's better to convert `l2` to a `set` and check for membership of each element of `l1` in `set(l2)`.

Membership tests take `O(n)` time for `lists` and `O(1)` time for `sets`. Using a `set` would reduce the time complexity of the required code to `O(n)`, which would have otherwise been `O(n2)`.

```py
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['b', 'c']

# Converting to a set takes O(n) time
s2 = set(l2)  # {'c', 'b'}


# Each of the following approaches takes O(n) time

# Normal approach
contains_n = []
for x in l1:
    contains_n.append(x in s2)


# Using a list comprehension
contains_lc = [
    x in s2
    for x in l1
]


# Using a functional approach
contains_f = list(map(lambda x: x in s2, l1))


print(f'contains_n: {contains_n}')
print(f'contains_lc: {contains_lc}')
print(f'contains_f: {contains_f}')
```

Output:

```py
contains_n: [False, True, True]
contains_lc: [False, True, True]
contains_f: [False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works too

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['b', 'c']

result = []
for i in l1 : 
  result.append(i in l2)
```

but it's long

Answer (score 0):

checking whether an element is in a list takes O(n) operations, if you're repeating this many times it's worth using a `set` which has membership tests of (amortised) O(1), giving you

```
def in1d(l1, l2):
  s2 = set(l2)
  return [x in s2 for x in l1]
```

(borrowing naming convention from [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html))

which will be much faster when the lists get large (i.e. more than a few hundred elements each)

Answer (score 0):

using `lambda`

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['b', 'c']

res = list(map(lambda x: x in l2, l1))

print(res)
```

output

```
[False, True, True]
```